# How many DB connections are open when Pyramid handles HTTP requests on top of CherryPy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid, cherrypy

Some background info, I'm building a web application on top of Pyramid Web Framework. In production, I use CherryPy as the WSGI server.

The question is: How is DB Connection is managed provided that I use Postgres + SQLAlchemy for DB access?

Comment: Please, provide more detail and code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The default SQLAlchemy setup uses [internal connection pooling](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html).

- Certain number of connections is created on process startup (depending on your setup you can have M processes running N threads)
- The connections are recycled across requests (if you have set up your SQLAlchemy connection properly, the question does not show any code for this)
- The pool can grow and if the maximum connection limit is reached an exception is risen